# svn + mirroring the repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversion-edge

I am trying to set up a mirror repository for my primary subversion repository. My requirement is whenever commit happens in the primary repository, the same commit should happen in the mirror repository also.

I have set up a sync script in the mirror server which will sync with the primary svn every 1 hour and it is syncing properly. The requirement now is to reduce the 1 hour sync frequency to zero. >> Mirror should be updated immediately after the commit in primary.

I have tried setting up, a post commit hook which will trigger the sync. But this is delaying the commits in the primary as it adds latency.

Is there any other possible options? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Run `svnsync synchronize` by hand after commit?

Comment: Post commit, running the sync in Back ground resolved the issue. Thanks.